# Tidal force of a black hole without using tetrad

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, tidal-effect

One thing I have been somewhat curious about is computing geodesic deviation for tidal effect. Specifically, given separation vector $\xi^a$ between two nearby timelike geodesics and $V^c$ the velocity vector fields tangent to the geodesics, we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{D\xi^a}{d\tau^2} = R^{a}_{\,\,bcd}V^bV^c\xi^d\,.
\end{equation}
Suppose I have a static spherically symmetric metric given by Schwarzschild metric, which only depends on radial coordinate $r$. The first step in computing tidal force, as is well-known, seems to be simplifying this expression. For example, if I wish to know how geodesics converge when two particles are placed side by side along $\phi$ direction, I expect that along this direction particles come closer together, as we expect from radial nature of gravity.

However, to do this explicitly, naively what I would do is to calculate for $\xi^\theta$, and in particular I choose $\xi^a$ such that initially only $\xi^\phi$ is nonzero. Then if pick $V^c$ such that the particles are initially at rest; this would lead to (?)
\begin{equation}
\frac{D\xi^\phi}{d\tau^2} = R^{\phi}_{\,\,tt\phi}\xi^\phi\,.
\end{equation}
Here is the problem: for Schwarzschild geometry, it can be shown that $R^{\phi}_{\,\,tt\phi}$ *vanishes* on the horizon of the black hole. This cannot be correct expression for tidal force, then, since it should be nonzero.

Curiously, repeating these calculations for weak-field limits (or far-distance limit of Schwarzschild black holes) do give the correct $r^{-3}$ dependence because the higher order terms can be neglected, and this expression seems to give reasonable tidal force if I am some distance away from the horizon (say, $2r_H$). This is true also for the "sphaghettification" scenario where instead one is interested in radial scenario; again, the same method (but now with different component of Riemann tensor) also leads to vanishing tidal force *at the horizon*, but good in weak field or some distance away from horizon. The problem arises because the component of Riemann tensor above also has a contribution at the order of $M^2/r^4$ which neatly cancels the usual "tidal" contribution at $r=r_H$. What is going on here?

I am aware of calculation methods using tetrads, but I am trying to stick this to elementary GR as much as I can.

**Note:** the (?) mark was meant to show that similar expression seems to appear *if* I do use tetrad formalism, and it might be possible that I am missing something, but I cannot tell why at the moment.

**Update**: I think I found the solution (thanks to comment from @A.V.S), but for personal reasons, I will write down the solution myself some time in April.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer this based on suggestion by A.V.S. in one of the answer posts. The problem is due to a common mistake in general relativity, namely $V^t = 1$ which is not correct unless one is in flat space. Taking this into account, the correct equation is
\begin{equation}
    \frac{D^2\xi^\phi}{d\tau^2} = R^\phi_{\,\,tt\phi}V^tV^t\xi^\phi\,.
\end{equation}
Now, clearly this is only valid at $\tau=0$ when the four-velocity has no spatial component, but that is fine since it's only for this one time-slice. Crucially, $V^tV^t = 1/f(r)$ and combining this with the Riemann tensor gives
\begin{equation}
\frac{D^2\xi^\phi}{d\tau^2} = -\frac{GM}{r^3}\xi^\phi
\end{equation}
which is exact. Here $r$ is the fixed radius where the two geodesics begin.

One possible complication when one wants to compute tidal force is whether to take $\xi^\phi$ to measure proper length or coordinate length: as it is given, this equation will give tidal force based on *coordinate separation*, while possibly one is interested in proper separation. I think this can be handled at least for this case, recognizing that along $\phi$ direction, proper length and coordinate length only differ by a fixed *constant* prefactor dependent on $f(r)$, where $r$ is a fixed radius..

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are trying to combine condition *the particles are initially at rest* with placement *at the horizon*. Massive object cannot be at rest at the horizon, since $\partial_t$ (in Schwarzschild coordinates) is null there. You need to include the radial component of the 4-velocity. Also note, that in Schwarzschild coordinates at the horizon the $g_{tt}$ metric component is zero, while $g_{rr}$ diverges, so be careful with that.

Comment: Thanks, I think I know how to fix the problem thanks to your reminder that at rest with the horizon is physically inconsistent. I will write the solution I found in April.